# Android 4.1 read assert folder audio path issue

Tags: android, audio, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In android 4.1(Jelly bean) not supporting offline audio in webview.It works fine in online version ie if file path is online.

```
<html>
<body>
 <audio src="file:///android_asset/folder/file/test.ogg" id="player" loop>Get an HTML5 browser!</audio>
 <form id="interface">
         <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="PlayPause()" id="playpause"/>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("player");

 function PlayPause()
 {
     if (audioPlayer.paused)
     {
         audioPlayer.play();
         document.getElementById("playpause").value = "Pause";
     }
     else
     {
         audioPlayer.pause();
         document.getElementById("playpause").value = "Play"; 
     }
 }  
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This code plays audio in all android version except webview of android 4.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: post us some code to work on yaar

Comment: are you running it in webview or default web browser ?

Comment: try adding this code : mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

Comment: I already checked .its not working..